# How to control print and cancel buttons on browser's print page?

Tags: java

I work on a Java web application on Eclipse.It has a screen, which some invoices are listed in a table.I can approve, edit,send via email,print or cancel the invoices via selecting them from the table.

When I click on print button, a MessageDialog gets opened and asks whether the user is sure to print the invoice, and I say yes.Then the browser's print page gets opened:

[image]

I want to be able to control the "Print" and "Cancel" buttons on these page.If I  click on "Print", the status of invoice is going to be "PRINTED".If I click on "CANCEL" the status of invoice is not going to change, it should remain same.
When I execute the following method on the class,it opens browser's print page.

```
    private void printPressed() {
    browserContent.execute("printMe();");
}
```

And I am stuck at these stage.I want to modify this method for the purpose of controlling "Print" and "Cancel" buttons.How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't as this will be security hole (Imagine that you make loop to print 1000000 pages of stg nasty). Every user must decide on his own.